# The router exports IPFIX data and templates from two different source id

Tags: cisco, netflow

I configure Netflow Flexible use IPFIX protocol on a Cisco router and receive IPFIX packet from it successfully. The router exports data-sets with an exporter (source id = 0) and template-sets with another exporter (source id = 1).

I was tested that before, by configuring a router on GNS3, but I received data-sets and template-sets from same exporter (source id).

Is it important to match data and template by their source-id and template-id? or I should match data and template by their template-id and source-ip!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID was replaced with an "observation domain", which is essentially the same thing, a unique 32-bit number indicating the source of the export.

Unfortunately, the templates from one source are not necessarily the same as templates from another -- even in the same device -- and therefore the data records may be formatted differently.   You will know this is going wrong when the data seems way out of whack.

You may be running into a configuration issue, here is some additional background into configuring flexible NetFlow:  http://www.flowtraq.com/corporate/blog/tech-thoughts/configuring-flexible-netflow-export-cisco-routers/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I used same configuration. I configured FNF on `Cisco ASR 1001-x` if it can help!

Comment: Odd.  My experience with the ASR series is that they export clean NetFlow.  What is your IOS version?

Comment: I think it's `Cisco IOS XE`, I don't have access to it now. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/asr-1001-x-router/index.html